# regex findall sentence excluding \n

Tags: python, regex

**Short question:**
Let's assume I have such a text:

```
sent one. sent two.
sent three
sent four
```

I want to get the sentences with a result like this:

```
['sent one.', 'sent two.', 'sent three', 'sent four']
```

**Long Question**:
I want to create in python a function that allows you to divide a text into sentences (but I don't want to use a tokenizer imported from another module).
As in the previous example, in addition to the newline there can be several separators that can cause a new sentence to start. Also, I may want to keep these separators in the sentence or not.
So because requirement can change dynamically, I would like to write a parameterized function that allows you to decide:

1. which are the separators that make the sentence break (for
   example \n . ! ? : ;)
2. which of these must be removed (for example \n)
3. in the presence of which characters the separators have the effect (e.g. \s, in some cases the separator should not work)

I didn't want to ask such a complex question because actually I had already written a code that worked in part but some things don't work and I'm afraid it's because of the newlines.
I show you a simplified version of the code, the regex inside it is dynamically generated, I show you only the resulted generated regex with the default parameters omitting the code for generation which is now useless for the question:

```
def tokeniz_text(text, separator=['.', '!', '?'], to_remove=['\n'], bordering=['\s']):
    ...regex generation...
    re_divide = r"""(.+?{}{}){}{}""".format(pre, sep, nxt, rem)
    ...generated regex...
    (.+?(?:(?<!\.)|(?<!!)|(?<!\?))(?:\.|!|\?))(?:\.|!|\?|\s)|(?:(?:\s*)(?:\n+)(?:\s*))
```

the reason why I chose findall and why it seemed the only method of RE that could allow me to decide whether to keep the separators unlike split (which, however, from what Tom says, maybe I have to reconsider. It seems to me that these are the only two methods that return a list of occurrences from the entire parsed string, so I don't consider the others).
Plus I wanted to use the dotall flag because as you can see I use the dot to capture characters, and I thought that if the dot automatically doesn't capture spaces, I could never decide to capture them.

Anyway, I hope that now the situation is not reversed and that the question is too complex!
Sorry if I explained it wrong, yesterday I was very sleepy and it's difficult to understand what to explain because it's not very clear to me either, I'll try again (even if Tim Biegeleisen's answer might be right).

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one attempt to get you started:

```
>>> s = '''\
sent one. sent two.
sent three
sent four'''

>>> import re
>>> re.split(r'[.\n]\s*', s)
['sent one', 'sent two', 'sent three', 'sent four']
```

The says, split on sentence delimiters where a delimiter is a period or newline either of which can be followed by zero or more spaces.

Answer (score 0):

We can try using `re.split` on the following pattern:

```
(?<=\.)\s+|\r?\n
```

This will split on dot, followed by any amount of whitespace, or on a CR?LF character.  Note that this approach retains the dots ending a sentence, since they only appear in the pattern as a fixed width lookbehind.

```
inp = """sent one. sent two.
sent three
sent four"""

matches = re.split(r'(?<=\.)\s+|\r?\n', inp)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['sent one.', 'sent two.', 'sent three', 'sent four']
```